# Backbone .on event listener with callback function with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

How can I correctly write this in coffee script?

```
this.model.on('change:game', function(){
  this.render();
}, this)
```

I am trying everything I can think of, and I'm currently on this:

```
@model.on 'change:game', -> 
  @render()
@
```

I am confused how to handle multiple arguments when one of them is an anonymous function, the first 2 parameters have a comma, but if I try to add a comma before the 3rd parameter I get syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need an anonymous function. When you say:

```
model.on(event, fn, context)
```

in JavaScript, the event handling system will end up saying:

```
fn.apply(context, whatever_arguments_are_used)
```

The `fn` can by any function at all, it doesn't have to be anonymous.

Moving to CoffeeScript and remembering that `@render` is a reference to the `render` function, we can say:

```
@model.on 'change:game', @render, @
```

and skip the anonymous function altogether. Alternatively, you could use [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) to automatically supply the desired `@`:

```
@listenTo @model, 'change:game', @render
```

This sort of structure can be a problem if the `fn` above takes arguments that don't match what the event system will pass. In those cases, you can use a [bound anonymous function as wmock suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34235854/479863), the multiline approach you found, or some parentheses:

```
@model.on 'change:game', (-> @render()), @
#                        ^            ^
```

or `listenTo` again:

```
@listenTo @model, 'change:game', -> @render()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
@model.on "change:game", => @render()
```

With CoffeeScript, you can leverage the "fat" arrows to lexically bind `this` and simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have four ways:

1. simple

   ```
   @model.on 'change:game', ->
     @render()
   , @
   ```
2. fat arrow

   ```
   @model.on 'change:game', => @render()
   ```
3. without anonymous function

   ```
   @model.on 'change:game', @render, @
   ```
4. with parenthesis

   ```
   @model.on 'change:game', (-> @render()), @
   ```

---

And Your second question about how to handle multiple parameters, when some of them are anonymous function.

Four examples, that explain everything:

## param, func

```
func param1, () ->
  # anonymous function 1
  return
```

## param, func, param

```
func param1, () ->
  # anonymous function 1
  return
, param2
```

## param, func, func

```
func param1, () ->
  # anonymous function 1
  return
, () ->
  # anonymous function 2
  return
```

## param, func, param, func

```
func param1, () ->
  # anonymous function 1
  return
, param2, () ->
  # anonymous function 2
  return
```